# convert True False matrix to image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a matrix consisting of True and False values. I want to print this as an image where all the True values are white and the False values are black. The matrix is called indices. I have tried the following:

```
indices = indices.astype(int)  #To convert the true to 1 and false to 0
indices*=255                   #To change all the 1's to 255
cv2.imshow('Indices',indices)
cv2.waitKey()
```

This is printing a fully black image. When I try, print `(indices==255).sum()`, it returns a values of 669 which means that there are 669 elements/pixels in the indices matrix which should be white. But I can only see a pure black image. How can I fix this?

Comment: Instead of `indices*=255`, try with `cv2.threshold()`, also try `cv2.imwrite("./debug.png", indices)` instead of `cv2.imshow()`

Comment: Which size is your matrix ? on an image large enough, it would be possible that your white points are simply lost among all the black dots

Comment: It is 600 by 900. I agree, but I know that all of those points are close together and form a definite shape.

Comment: What if you use a `float`?

Comment: That fixed it. That was a surprise. Do you know what the problem with `int` could be?

Comment: @Sibi: I think opencv usually represent an image as a matrix of floats ranging from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, `opencv` represents an image as a matrix of floats ranging from 0 to 1, or an integer with values **between the minimum and the maximum** of that type.

An `int` has no bounds (except the boundaries of what can be represented with all available memory). If you however use `np.uint8`, that means you are working with (unsigned) bytes, where the minimum is 0 and the maximum 255.

So there are several options. The two most popular would be:

1. cast to `np.uint8` and then multiply with 255:

   ```
   indices = indices.astype(np.uint8)  #convert to an unsigned byte
    indices*=255
    cv2.imshow('Indices',indices)
    cv2.waitKey()
   ```
2. Use a `float` representation:

   ```
   indices = indices.astype(float)
    cv2.imshow('Indices',indices)
    cv2.waitKey()
   ```

Note that you could also choose to use `np.uint16` for instance to use unsigned 16-bit integers. In that case you will have to multiply with 65'535. The advantage of this approach is that you can use an arbitrary color depth (although most image formats use 24-bit colors (8 bits per channel), there is no reason not to use 48-bit colors. If you for instance are doing image processing for a glossy magazine, then it can be beneficial to work with more color depth.

Furthermore even if the end result is a 24-bit colorpalette, one can sometimes better use a higher color depth for the different steps in image processing.

Comment: #1 would produce a greyscale image, and not an RGB image. Try [this](https://bin.garudalinux.org/?d03274bd2f771d0f#Gh4LwL1JNQYo6KznReJNR9WHX3ku3dkSV6SCx5btPphc) instead:
        `# array is your boolean array, and rgb is the rgb_color of your choosing`

        `binary_image_stack = np.zeros((*array.shape, 3), dtype=np.uint8)`

        `binary_image_stack[array == boolean_indexes] = rgb_color`

Comment: float doesnt seem to work unless by img*255 too

Comment: @pippo1980 I rolled your edit back because it went against the intent of the author. you added a line of code that changed the result of the code. editing is a privilege you should exercise with more restraint.

Comment: Yep, I tried everything is cv2.imwrite that doesnt work not cv2.imshow